# Kotlin Function Literal with Any Receiver type

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make kotlin accept an interface type as a receiver for a function but I get a compile error saying type mismatch.

Here is an example:

```
interface Foo

class Bar : Foo

fun main() {
    val l = initBar {

    }

    initFoo(l) // Doesnt work compile error: Type mismatch.
                                                //Required:
                                                //  Foo.() → Unit
                                                //Found:
                                                //  Bar.() → Unit
}

fun initBar(init: Bar.() -> Unit) = init


fun initFoo(init: Foo.() -> Unit) = Unit
```

I get the following compile error from this code

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Foo.() → Unit
Found:
Bar.() → Unit
```

Is there any way to make the initFoo function accept any reciever object that implements `Foo` without casting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a generic type for it:

```
fun <T: Foo> initFoo(init: T.() -> Unit) = Unit
```

Note this limits what you can do with it inside the function. Since you accept a function that could be called on a specific type, you can't call the passed-in lambda on any Foo.

```
fun <T: Foo> initFoo(init: T.() -> Unit) {
    val someFoo = object: Foo {}
    someFoo.init() // ERROR (type mismatch)
}
```

This is because, for instance, your `Bar.() -> Unit` function could be using properties and functions of `Bar` that are not necessarily part of any arbitrary `Foo`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the use of Generic types/casting to minimize runtime overhead. I'd figure that using the Interface implementation type or Any would allow this code to work, but I guess not.

Comment: Generics don't add overhead unless the type is a primitive, which must then be wrapped. Using a lambda is orders of magnitude more overhead than a cast. It's not worth worrying about unless you're calling this function tens of thousands of times all at once.

Comment: It will be called a lot. The lambdas are cached and stored in memory so there wont be practically any overhead at runtime after startup. Right now it's casting every time it invokes one of these lambdas and I was just hoping I could avoid that. I guess I'll have to go back to using generics if there is no other choice. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid generics if you can. They tend to proliferate and make composition more challenging. As inheritance structures (does anyone still use inheritance?) become deeper the variance and covariance issues will boil your brain.